# No code completion using buildSrc with gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I was spoiled with the buildSrc folder. All my dependencies are declared in there and I simply reference them from my app modules to make dependency management simple and effective. Recently though, something broke. I no longer get auto-complete suggestions when typing (e.g. typing Library. would give me a list of all strings it contains). Also, the reference is no longer found so the code isnt clickable. I believe it started working with Android Studio 3.3.

Just for context, heres how I reference my dependencies in my app module. My buildSrc folder has a file with the Library object, which in turn contains a String labeled RecyclerView (pointing to 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview...')

[image: Gradle dependencies block]

My build.gradle file in the buildSrc folder labeled
'build.gradle.kts'

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

Also worth mentioning that this exact code and setup worked fine earlier on, the only way Ive changed it is adding in more dependencies to the Library object etc. Syntax works fine there so I dont think I need to include the code from there (poke me if you still want me to include it though).

Edit: A typo came through. Library above should be Libraries.

Comment: Same problem here. Have you found a solution in the meanwhile?

Comment: @harry248 Perhaps not a solution, but if using ".kts" and a slightly different script it works - still on the lookout for an actual fix!

Comment: @zoltish did you find a fix for this?

Comment: @RafiqulHasan Im afraid not :x I did however find that .kts files severely broke my project when adding new modules (due to build.gradle files being created on top of the .kts ones) though so Im just rocking the above and typing out dependencies without any autocorrect for now.

Comment: @zoltish There is an open issue on the Google Issue Tracker about this.
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123032843.
They fixed it in Android Studio 3.5 canary 12. I haven't tried it yet. You can give it a go.

Comment: @RafiqulHasan Cool, thanks for letting me know. Ill hold for the stable release of AS 3.5 :)

Comment: Same issue here. Google confirmed that in Android Studio 3.5 Beta 4 the bug has been fixed :D
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123032843